# mongo DB print key of a field

Tags: mongodb, printf, key

Assume, I have a User collection with many fields. I know a user mail for example test@test.com. I am looking on a way to print the Key of `test@test.com` which is "`email`" in mongo print output.

```
{"email":"test@test.com"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the document you are interested in, project such that **only** the `email` attribute is returned and then grab the field name from the returned document. For example:

```
db.collection.find(
        // find all documents (you'll probably have your own criteria to add here)
        {}, 
        // project on the email attribute and - to reduce noise - exclude
        // the default _id projection 
        {email: 1, '_id': 0}
    )
    // it would make sense to limit here since you are only interested in an attribute name 
    // and, presumably, all relevant documents would have the same attribute name
    .limit(1)
    // since you only projected on email the returned document is
    // expected to have a single attribute
    .forEach(function(myDoc) { 
        for (var key in myDoc) {
            // print the attribute name
            print("key: " + key);    
        }     
    })
```

FWIW, this is ~unusual not least since if you know you are interested in the email attribute then why would you need to write code to get your hands on it :) Perhaps if you provide more detail on **why** you want to do this another solution might become apparent.

If you are looking for a generic solution to 'find me the names of all keys' in my docs then something like this might be better:

```
db.collection.find(
        // find all documents (you'll probably have your own criteria to add here)
        {}, 
        // to reduce noise exclude the default _id projection 
        {'_id': 0}
    )
    // it would make sense to limit here since you are only interested in an attribute name 
    // and, presumably, all relevant documents would have the same attribute name
    .limit(1)
    .forEach(function(myDoc) { 
        for (var key in myDoc) {
            // print the attribute name
            print("key: " + key);    
        }     
    })
```